# Android html image prob

Tags: html, image, android-webview, loaddata

I am displaying a text file that contains html code in a webview using `loadData()`. The html code has a image tag like `<img src="file:///android_asset/test.png" alt="cd4+ cell">` and placed the test.png file in the `res\drawable` folder. But webview is displaying perfect without the img. Where is the probelm in my system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `loadDataWithBaseUrl()` instead of `loadData()`.  Something like this:

```
public void loadHTML() {  
    final String mimeType = "text/html";  
    final String encoding = "utf-8";  
    final String html = "<img src=\"file:///android_asset/test.png\" />";  

    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(yourIDhere);  
    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://not/needed", html, mimeType, encoding, ""); 
}
```

Comment: It is not just a short html...it is a long html file...i am reading it from the file and displaying it by loadData(). this html contains the image.

Answer (score 0):

you can see CDATA or into above code you can add your tages