# Access a drawable resource as an image in a webview

Tags: android, resources, android-webview

I have a png file in my package, and I just want to use it as the source for an image I am loading via html in a webview.

So far I have tried, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534043/android-add-image-to-webview-from-a-drawable), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066778/android-html-image-prob) and [this](http://androidbook.blogspot.com/2009/08/referring-to-android-resources-using.html).  None of which have actually worked.

Here is how I am adding the img tag to the html.  Can anyone help me? I'm trying to build this for as early of an SDK version as possible (currently 4 [1.6])

```
String stringPath = "fie:///android_asset/chat_bubble.png";
addOn = String.format("<img src=\"%s\" >", stringPath);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I assume you copied the code piece from your project.)

There is a typo:

```
String stringPath = "fie:///android_asset/chat_bubble.png";
```

should be

```
String stringPath = "file:///android_asset/chat_bubble.png";
```

And you didn't closed `<img>` tag:

```
addOn = String.format("<img src=\"%s\" >", stringPath);
```

should be

```
addOn = String.format("<img src=\"%s\" />", stringPath);
```

Comment: Turns out it was that damn missing 'l' the entire time >< hate typo bugs, thank you for spotting that

Comment: @faradaj: Do you know how to do the same with the system resources, like `@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details.png`?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, generalize as you see fit:

1> Add your PNG file to the res/assets dir.
2> Create a string that contains ALL of your HTML code to be displayed.
3> Make sure to use the below format for the image you want to display:

```
"<img src=\"file:///android_asset/my_image_goes_here.png\" />"
```

Here's the sample code:

```
final StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();    

s.append("<html>");                             
s.append("<body>");
s.append("<img src=\"file:///android_asset/my_image_goes_here.png\" />");
s.append("</body>");                            
s.append("</html>");
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, s.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630829/android-display-res-viewable-in-webview), but you should use drawables.

Regards, 
 Stéphane

Comment: Doesn't help at all, thats really just more of the same above.  The accepted answer only works for 2.2+, and I use it in assets in my code currently